# Participle clauses

Tags: present-participles, to-infinitive

Studying participles with adverbial meaning, I got to know how to shorten complex sentences with the help of V-ing. The topic is quite clear, but I'm wondering about the difference in meaning if we use 'to' instead of V-ing.

e.g.

**She needed some help studying for her exams.**

and

**She needed some help to study for her exams.**

Comment: I suggest you look  up which verbs must take "to" and which verbs don't have to take "to". The first is more notional and refers to what she needs. The second is more "purpose oriented". That is the difference in meaning. Some verbs can take either and there is a subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: She needed some help *in* study for her exams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To* in this situation works like *in order to*.

> She needed some help to study for her exams.

She can't study until she gets the help.

> She needed some help studying for her exams.

She can study, or might be studying now, but will do that better if she receives the help.